# Enviar valor de um input radio para o php

Tags: php

Boa tarde, tenho um formulário que vai me enviar os dados do usuário via email, e tenho 3 `input type="radio"` que cada um me informa o que o usuário quer, como faço pra enviar os valores dele para o php?

```js
var frm = $("#form-carro");
    frm.submit(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./form-carro.php",
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function () {
                $("#cform").append("<div class='alert alert-success'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>×</button><i class='fa fa-thumbs-o-up'></i><strong>Obrigado!</strong> Sua mensagem foi enviada!</div>")
            }
        }), e.preventDefault()
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form-carro">
  <label class="margem-direita" style="margin-right: 5%" for='seguro'>
    <input id='seguro-novo' type="radio" name="seguro" value="Seguro Novo">Seguro Novo</label>
  <label class="margem-direita" style="margin-right: 5%" for='seguro'>
    <input id='renovacao' type="radio" name="seguro" value="Renovação">Renovação</label>
  <label class="margem-direita" for='seguro'>
    <input id='sinistrado' type="radio" name="seguro" value="Sinistrado">Sinistrado</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Falta definir o `action` que é o arquivo php a ser executado, o método de envio e um botão submit.

Comment: @rray o action ta definido pela ajax, vou adicionar ele ao código

Comment: Isso, vai adicionando os detalhes ai, ante não tinha essa informação hehe.

Comment: @MauroAlexandre entáo é só colocar isso `$_POST['seguro'];` no php que realiza o envio que ele envia o valor selecionado do `name="seguro"`?

Comment: É mais ou menos isso, quando o ajax enviar o request o PHP  vai responder mostrando o valor do input

Comment: Qual problema vc tem, a requisição não chega (404)? o valor não é enviado, verifique com `print_r($_POST)` no php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Começa por ter alguns erros e faltas no seu html, o erro é que não fecha as tags `<label>` e presumo que queira enviar a informação com o metodo http `POST`, que é definido na tag `<form>` e a action que é o script `php` que vai processar a informação do lado do servidor.

```
<form id="form-carro" method="POST" action="script.php"> <!-- AJUSTAR AQUI O NOME DO FICHEIRO PHP -->
  <label class="margem-direita" style="margin-right: 5%" for='seguro-novo'>
    <input id='seguro-novo' type="radio" name="seguro" value="Seguro Novo">Seguro Novo</label>
  </label>
  <label class="margem-direita" style="margin-right: 5%" for='renovacao'>
    <input id='renovacao' type="radio" name="seguro" value="Renovação">Renovação</label>
  </label>
  <label class="margem-direita" for='sinistrado'>
    <input id='sinistrado' type="radio" name="seguro" value="Sinistrado">Sinistrado</label>
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

No script.php (este pode ter o nome que quiser):

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if(isset($_POST['seguro'])) {
        echo $_POST['seguro'];
    }
}
```

Nota que se quiser que os dados sejam processados na mesma página/ficheiro do formulário basta não definir a action no `<form>`:

```
<form id="form-carro" method="POST">
```

E incluir o php que está em cima na mesma página.

**EDIÇÃO (reparei pelos comentários na pergunta que está a fazer com ajax):**

Fiz um pequeno mas completo exemplo, pode testa-lo colocando isto tudo no mesmo ficheiro.php (tal como está) no servidor, ou pode colocar a parte php noutro ficheiro e definindo o url correto no pedido ajax:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if(isset($_POST['seguro'])) {
        echo $_POST['seguro'];
    }
    die();
}
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form-carro" method="POST">
  <label class="margem-direita" style="margin-right: 5%" for='seguro-novo'>
    <input id='seguro-novo' type="radio" name="seguro" value="Seguro Novo">Seguro Novo</label>
  </label>
  <label class="margem-direita" style="margin-right: 5%" for='renovacao'>
    <input id='renovacao' type="radio" name="seguro" value="Renovação">Renovação</label>
  </label>
  <label class="margem-direita" for='sinistrado'>
    <input id='sinistrado' type="radio" name="seguro" value="Sinistrado">Sinistrado</label>
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
<script>
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var seg = $('input[name="seguro"]:checked').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {seguro: seg},
        success: function (response) {
            // aqui coloca tudo o que quer que aconteça caso a requisição seja bem sucedida
            // trabalha os dados que vieram do servidor como quiser
            alert('escolheu: ' +response);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error){
            console.log("Fail: " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Para funcionar com o  `frm.serialize()` do form, tente desta maneira:

```
<?php

if ($_POST) {
  echo $_POST['seguro'];
die();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var frm = $("#form_carro");
            frm.submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: frm.attr('action'),
                    data: frm.serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        /* o alert irá imprimir o
                           retorno do que foi 
                           enviado para o PHP */
                        alert(data);
                        $("#cform").append("<div class='alert alert-success'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>×</button><i class='fa fa-thumbs-o-up'></i><strong>Obrigado!</strong> Sua mensagem foi enviada!</div>")
                    },
                    error:function(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="cform"></div>
<form id="form_carro" method="post" action="./form-carro.php">
    <label class="margem-direita" style="margin-right: 5%" for='seguro'>
        <input id='seguro-novo' type="radio" name="seguro" value="Seguro Novo">Seguro Novo</label>
    <label class="margem-direita" style="margin-right: 5%" for='seguro'>
        <input id='renovacao' type="radio" name="seguro" value="Renovação">Renovação</label>
    <label class="margem-direita" for='seguro'>
        <input id='sinistrado' type="radio" name="seguro" value="Sinistrado">Sinistrado</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```